# Change "Related" algorithm

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

Example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696716/c-why-is-variable-a-function-and-not-an-object#23696750) C++ question has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array?rq=1) (in)famous but completely unrelated Java question listed under Related questions on the right side of the screen (at least for me, I don't know if it's partly user-specific). The most vexing parse of C++ has nothing what so ever to do with branch prediction of CPUs, or Java.

My assumption is, this happens because of the number of upvotes the Java question and its answers have. If this is true, then suggestion:

**When doing calculation for related questions, limit the upvotes and other similar numbers used in determining how related they are.**

Limiting could be either simple `effective_score = min(real_score, 100)`, or logarithmic, or whatever fits current implementation. After some amount of total upvotes, it shouldn't make any difference to relevancy, if there are 200 or 20000 total votes on related Q&A.

---

If above suggestion is all wrong technically and calculating related questions doesn't work anything like that, the issue itself still stands. For example this particular Java question keeps popping up for no reason, and I'm kinda sick of it actually...

---

Note: I'm not sure if this should be tagged [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) instead of, or in addition to [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). This does have the practical effect of making it harder to find good dupes (because unrelated but highly voted questions push other Qs off the list), at least. Feel free to edit tags if appropriate.

Comment: You are right that the most vexing parse is unrelated to branch-prediction or java, but your example question is also tagged C++ for good and sufficient reason, so the proposed related articles are not quite as far off as you intimated.

Comment: Oh, many of the related articles are fine, but the three (as shown to me at this moment) with quadruple-digit score are all unrelated. That alone wastes 30% of related questions space on the page, not insignificant. Would they be replaced with something potentially more related, if score was capped for the purpose of calculation? In this suggestion, I hope so.

Comment: about 50% of [C] questions link to: [improve insert per second performance of sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) even if there is no [sqlite] tag.  Perhaps the algorithm could correlate the relationship of one tag to another based on how often they appear together.